# Local costmap has unknown space where no obstacle in laser range

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
in my simulations the local costmap has unknown space for directions where there is no obstacle, see image:
[image: image description]

I think it should be the same or a similar problem described here: http://answers.ros.org/question/190170/local-cost-map-not-updated/

How do I fix this? The other thread also offers no clear solution.

Thanks,
Micha

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218653/local-costmap-has-unknown-space-where-no-obstacle-in-laser-range/) by [Micha Sende](https://answers.ros.org/users/23012/micha-sende/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2015-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once again, I answer myself: The solution is to unset the following parameter for the local costmap:

```
track_unknown_space: false
```

For the global costmap the parameter is still true though.

---

Originally posted by [Micha Sende](https://answers.ros.org/users/23012/micha-sende/) with karma: 65 on 2015-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1